# C# insert values into an Access Database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a problem while inserting variables into a database.

Here is an example from the code:

`int rezultat = 0;`

This is in `form1`.

Then in the second form I have:

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
   OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\tom\Desktop\snake2\snake\snake\Database1.mdb";
        string ime = textBox1.Text;
        string scoore = rezultat;
        connect.Open();
       // MessageBox.Show("dela");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into rezultati( ime, rezultat" + "values (@ime, @scoore )", connect);

    }
```

The database is connected correctly, but if I click the button an error appears.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please post the message.

Comment: you don't even populate your parameters. Be sure to populate the parameters collection in the same order as they are used in the `Insert` statement

Comment: Not allowed to change the "ConnectionString"property.the connection's current state is open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inorder to move them from your program to your query.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into rezultati(ime, rezultat) " + " values (@ime, @scoore )", connect);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ime",OleDbType.Char).value = textBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@scoore",OleDbType.Char).value = rezultat;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that named parameters are not supported so you *must* add your parameters in the same order they are used int eh query. Sometimes Access is fine with the `@abc` syntax and sometimes you need to use a `?` palce holder. I forget what is standard for the OleDb/Mdb interaction.

As for your connection string problem, have you seen [this site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2003/) and tried a connection string like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\tom\Desktop\snake2\snake\snake\Database1.mdb;
User Id=admin;Password=;
```

Comment: thanks but now I have an syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @user3463948 yeah, I didn't see there was no space before `values` and no close parens. try with that code.

Comment: @LarsTech I added some info about his connection string too. I wrote this before his comment :/

Comment: now I get an new error: not allowed to change the"connectionString"property. the connection's current state is open.

Comment: That happens when you Open the connection?

Comment: no, that happens when I click on the button to add the scoore and the name into the base.

Comment: but not on the line which opens the connection? What line does it happen on then?